# Ошибка на mdn в главе Strict mode

Tags: javascript, документация

1. Там написано: "перечисленные в сериализованном объекте", но в примере сериализованного объекта нету.
2. Со строгим режимом исключение не выбрасывается:

```js
"use strict";
var o = { p: 1, p: 2 };
console.log('Всё работает');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Статья](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не ошибка, обратите внимание на на текст в рамочке. Там написано "Это уже не является проблемой в ECMAScript 2015". Поэтому, если вы возьмете старый браузер, без поддержки ECMAScript 2015, например "любимый" всеми  IE, то увидите ошибку "Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть этот синтаксис допустим? Зачем? Разве это когда-либо бывает нужно? Скорее ошибка программиста

Comment: Вот тут есть небольшое обсуждение на эту тему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286122/why-is-object-with-duplicated-property-accepted-in-javascript